# License Activation and Saving Activated License

Tags: java, license4j

I use License4J for my Java software; it supports license activation over internet but 
I need help on how to save and load activated license text.

```
String licenseKey = "AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE";
String publickey = "30819f300d06092a864...e32fb70203010001";
String internalString = "1395297610268";
String nameforValidation = null;
String companyforValidation = null;
int hardwareIDMethod = 0;

License license = LicenseValidator.validate(
                licenseKey,
                publickey,
                internalString,
                nameforValidation,
                companyforValidation,
                hardwareIDMethod);
System.out.println("License Validation Status: " + license.getValidationStatus());

License activatedLicense = LicenseValidator.autoActivate(license, "https://myServer/algas/autoactivate");
System.out.println("License Activation Status: " + activatedLicense.getActivationStatus());
```

Here I can have activated license text string from `activatedLicense.getLicenseString();`

If I save this string on disk, how to validate it on each startup; and is hardware id for activated license stored inside license text or do I have to specify hardware id in validation method?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about proprietary software. Ask the softwware vendor for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate activated license text just like a normal license text. Hardware id information is already stored in license text.

```
License license = LicenseValidator.validate(
        licenseString,
        publickey,
        productID,
        productEdition,
        productVersion,
        currentDate,
        productReleaseDate);
```